# Do spells cast through magic items require expensive material components?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, spell-components

I have a *Staff of the Woodlands*, which allows me to cast the spell *Awaken*. *Awaken* has an expensive material component of "an agate worth at least 1,000 gp, which the spell consumes". Is that agate required and consumed when *Awaken* is cast through the *Staff*, or does casting it through the *Staff* somehow modify or remove that requirement?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

No they do not require components at all including somatic or verbal for that matter. So casting an Arcane Lock from a Staff of the Magi doesn't require the 25g worth of gold dust nor would the Staff of the Woodlands require it for Awaken. It may seem "overpowered" but the typical druid doesn't go around making sentient armies of animals for good reason.

DMG p141 the section on magical items and casting spells from them.

> The spell is cast at the lowest possible spell level, doesn't expend any of the user's spell slots, and ***requires no components***, unless the item's description says otherwise.

Comment: My assumption, and ruling in my own games, would have been the opposite. Thank you!