# Does a spell scroll remove the need for ‘special’ material components?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, spell-components

The description of a [spell scroll](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/spell-scroll) in the DMG states:

> If the spell is on your class’s spell list, you can read the scroll
>   and cast its spell without providing any material components.

Does this also apply to spells that require ‘special’ components — the sort that a components pouch would not cater for? For example, *Plane Shift* requires a tuning fork specifically tuned to the destination plane; *Imprisonment* requires a variety of components depending upon the type of restraint being inflicted. Do scrolls of these spells no longer require these fancy components to cast?

Comment: Related: [Do these spells require access to the material components for the spell even when cast from a Ring of Spell Storing?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/125592)

Answer (score 9):

## Yes, components are not needed to cast from a spell scroll

The DMG covers this under [Chapter 7 - Activating a Magic Item](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/treasure#MagicItems) (emphasis mine):

> Some magic items allow the user to cast a spell from the item, often by expending charges from it. The spell is cast at the lowest possible spell and caster level, doesn’t expend any of the user’s spell slots, and **requires no components** unless the item’s description says otherwise.

A Scroll is a magic item and thus follows the above guidance on activating it. Do note that this casting is a one-time event:

> The writing vanishes from a scroll when it is read. Once used, a consumable item loses its magic and no longer functions

Comment: This makes sense for spells in which the material component is consumed during the casting. However, it's less clear how this would work if the scroll was for a spell such as, say, Drawmij’s Instant Summons, where the material component is not consumed by the casting but becomes a retained trigger for the delayed part of the spell (“At any time thereafter, you can use your action to speak the item’s name and crush the sapphire. The item instantly appears in your hand regardless of physical or planar distances, and the spell ends”). Any ideas on that score?

Comment: @RickLecoat This is a separate question you should ask separately.

Comment: @RickLecoat It works the same everywhere. The quoted rule is simply "requires no components".

Comment: @NautArch in fact I think it has been asked before.

Comment: @RickLecoat I've added a new question to discuss those very interesting points. https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/150327

Comment: Since the necessity of having the gem to resolve _Drawmij's Instant Summons_, & the chest for _Leomund's Tiny Chest_, has been established in the answers to that question, I think that mentioning the existence of such caveats, would improve this answer.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. The components are used when the scroll is scribed.

From [*Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, p. 133](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/xgte/downtime-revisited#ScribingaSpellScroll):

> Scribing a spell scroll takes an amount of time and money related to the level of the spell the character wants to scribe, as shown in the Spell Scroll Costs table. In addition, the character must have proficiency in the Arcana skill and must provide any material components required for the casting of the spell.

See [How can a character create a Spell Scroll?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/78353/how-can-a-character-create-a-spell-scroll) for more.

Comment: Interesting. That suggests that in creating a spell scroll for a spell that requires different, specific components according to the precise effect of the spell, the scroll is effectively locked to a *particular version* of the spell, as determined by the components used in its creation. (eg. with Plane Shift the particular alloy of the tuning fork is specific to the plane being travelled to, so a spell scroll of Plane Shift would only allow travel to a specific plane, not ANY plane).

Comment: Along with mention that caveats exist such as needing the gem for _Drawmij's Instant Summons_, I think NautArch's answer would benefit from this citation, showing that the materials components are used when casting the spell _into_ the scroll.

Comment: @RickL: On Critical Role, Matt Mercer found a sensible narrative explanation for that: the scroll case included a tuning fork as well as a scroll.  But RAW, you can scribe multiple scrolls using the same tuning fork; mechanically you don't have to pack each scroll with a tuning fork since it's not consumed.  But then yes, it would make sense for it to be locked in.  This is the point where a DM has to step in and do some world-building for their campaign world about the fine details of how magic works, because the rules as written leave open questions (unless a later book nails down more.)

Answer (score -2):

All components are used when scribing the scroll. So technically you could choose to make a Scroll of Imprisonment useless for your players by stating that the materials used to craft the scroll included a statuette of a boss they already killed.

That would really upset your players though. You should probably ask your wizard to do an arcana check on the scroll so he knows the specific conditions of it and make sure it's still useful to them but only for one of your bosses, maybe introduce a new boss in this way.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).