# Can you store a Wished spell inside a Ring of Spell Storing?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, wish

The [*wish*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish) spell enables you to emulate any spell of 8th level or lower.

A [Ring of Spell Storing](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-spell-storing) enables you to store up to a 5th level spell inside it for later use.

My question is: can you store a *wished* spell (of 5th level or lower) into a Ring of Spell Storing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## No

The Ring of Spell Storing says:

> Any creature can cast a spell of 1 through 5th level into the ring by touching the ring as the spell is cast.

However, *wish* does not cast spells. It duplicates their effects.
Wish states that you can use it to:

> ...**duplicate the effect** of any other spell of 8th level or lower. You
> don't need to meet the requirements of that spell, it simply **takes
> effect**.

No matter what effect you duplicate, the spell you are casting is still *wish*. And, because *wish* is a 9th level spell, it cannot be stored in the Ring.

Comment: As a side note, the ring of spell storing doesn't take away material components, so the use of this exploit, even if it did work, is *shrug*

Comment: @BlakeSteel: Not quite sure I understand this. *Wish* does remove the need for components. And casting from the Ring should not require any components (per [this Q&A](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/124695/does-casting-a-spell-from-an-ioun-stone-ring-of-spell-storing-require-components)).

Comment: Missed that line in the DMG, whoops

Answer (score 2):

### No

The spell you cast is *wish*, the effect is that of a lower level spell.

### This is Wish We're Talking About

You could cast wish, and wish to store a spell into the ring of storing, but that isn't just duplicating the effect of the spell, so there may be consequences:

> You might be able to achieve something beyond the scope of the above examples. State your wish to the GM as precisely as possible. The GM has great latitude in ruling what occurs in such an instance; the greater the wish, the greater the likelihood that something goes wrong. This spell might simply fail, the effect you desire might only be partly achieved, or you might suffer some unforeseen consequence as a result of how you worded the wish.
>
> The stress of casting this spell to produce any effect other than duplicating another spell weakens you. After enduring that stress, each time you cast a spell until you finish a long rest, you take 1d10 necrotic damage per level of that spell.

What your asking for isn't too big, consider you spent a 9th level slot for a <=5 level spell to go into an item made to hold spells of levels <= 5.  So, the DM *should* be alright to try.

Comment: One thing worth noting potentially is that your second part would allow the caster to essentially store a component-free version of any <=5th level spell that can be used by anybody. Probably not that big a deal though. Also, it would be not worth the risk of not being able to cast *wish* again IMO.

Comment: "I wish that the next 8th level spell that I cast would be treated as a 5th level spell"?  Of course DM would probably scale the power/effectiveness down to compensate.

Comment: "I wish that I had a ring of spell storing containing <spell>"

Comment: @JeremyWeirich: if only wish could create magic items, players could get into all kinds of capers.

Comment: @outis *wish* can, at the DM's discretion, create magic items, but it carries with it all the dangers that the wish spell bring with it. Sure you can Vecna's hand, but it might come attached to some evil wielder. Sure, you can have a Holy Avenger...  through the heart...  I might not take it to that extreme it depends on the level of the player and the request of the ask and how they word it.

Comment: @J.A.Streich: The player _wished_ for a Holy Avenger and didn't get any more specific about the item?  _poof_ They just summoned Steve Rogers and his confessor. :)