# Can your familiar use the frozen spell bead from Arcane Abeyance to indirectly let you concentrate on a 2nd spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, spellcasting, familiars, concentration

[Arcane Abeyance](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#ChronurgyMagic) (p184 EGtW)Says:

> ...A creature holding the bead can use its action to release the spell within, whereupon the bead disappears. The spell uses your spell attack bonus and save DC, and the spell treats the creature who released it as the caster for all other purposes.

[Find Familiar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar) (p240 PHB) Says:

> ...In combat, it rolls its own initiative and acts on its own turn. A familiar can't attack, but it can take other actions as normal.

Can a familiar accept the frozen spell bead and then use it to cast a spell, if so does the familiar concentrate on the spell instead of the original caster?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Yes, depending on how the spell targets creatures

Rubiksmoose gave an excellent break down of what an attack is [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/169617/is-shove-an-attack), but what's relevant to this question can be found on *p.193-194, PHB*:

> Whether you're striking with a melee weapon, firing a weapon at range, or **making an attack roll as part of a spell**, an attack has a simple structure
>
> If there’s ever any question whether something you’re doing counts as an attack, the rule is simple: if you’re making an attack roll, you’re making an attack.

As a familiar is not able to attack (excluding a Warlock Pact of the Chain familiar), but there is no mention to a familiar's ability to cast a spell, then the familiar should be able to cast any spell that does **not** require an attack roll.
The other question that may come up is the  familiars ability to complete the components of the spell, but [as answered here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/124695/does-casting-a-spell-from-an-ioun-stone-ring-of-spell-storing-require-components) in regards to magic items casting spells,  *DMG p.141* states:

> The spell is cast at the lowest possible spell level, doesn't expend any of the user's spell slots, and requires no components, **unless the item's description says otherwise.**

The bead created from Arcane Abeyance is a magical item, and would follow the rules of magic items from above, meaning the components of the spell would be irrelevant to the familiar's ability to cast the spell.
In regards to the concentration of the spell in question, [Arcane Abeyance](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#ChronurgyMagic) states, as you've linked:

> ...A creature holding the bead can use its action to release the spell within, whereupon the bead disappears. The spell uses your spell attack bonus and save DC, and **the spell treats the creature who released it as the caster for all other purposes.**

The only places the spell would not use the familiars abilities are on the spell attack bonus (irrelevant for a familiar) or spell save DC.  All other aspects of the spell would be the responsibility of the familiar, including concentration.

Comment: So it does not "let you concentrate on a 2nd spell", it just lets the familiar cast the spell.

Comment: @enkryptor it **indirectly** will allow this spellcaster to have 2 of there own spells being concentrated on simultaneously, as asked.