# Does the Order of Scribes wizard's "Master Scrivener" feature remove the need for costly material components?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, wizard, spell-components

The [Order of Scribes](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#OrderofScribes) wizard's [Master Scrivener](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#MasterScrivener-2986122) feature provides the ability to create a magic scroll of 1st or 2nd level (TCoE, p. 78):

> Whenever you finish a long rest, you can create one magic scroll by
> touching your Wizardly Quill to a blank piece of paper or parchment
> and causing one spell from your Awakened Spellbook to be copied onto
> the scroll.
>
> The spellbook must be within 5 feet of you when you make the scroll.
> The chosen spell must be of 1st or 2nd level and must have a casting
> time of 1 action. Once in the scroll, the spell’s power is enhanced,
> counting as one level higher than normal. You can cast the spell from
> the scroll by reading it as an action. The scroll is unintelligible to
> anyone else, and the spell vanishes from the scroll when you cast it
> or when you finish your next long rest.

Does casting a spell through the scroll created this way require material components? For example, could I cast Find Familiar or Arcane Lock through the scroll without having to spend the 10gp / 25gp component?

Comment: Related on [Does a spell scroll remove the need for ‘special’ material components?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/150233)

Comment: I'm not sure if the above is a duplicate or not. Not 100% sure the scriveners scroll is the same thing because it does work differently.

Comment: Also, are you asking about creating the scroll, casting it, or something else?

Comment: Related: [Does an artificer's Spell-Storing Item bypass the need for costly/consumed material components?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/174416/does-an-artificers-spell-storing-item-bypass-the-need-for-costly-consumed-mater)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Costly components are not required.

The rules for casting a spell from a magic item state:

> Some magic items allow the user to cast a spell from the item, often by expending charges from it. The spell is cast at the lowest possible spell and caster level, doesn’t expend any of the user’s spell slots, and **requires no components unless the item’s description says otherwise.**

If the feature required costly components it would say so.

Comment: For clarity: are the material components are still required for crafting the scroll, as is definitely required for a non-*Master Scrivener* character?

Comment: @Upper_Case I think that's a different question, but the creation rules for it seem fairly clear.

Comment: @NautArch On review I think that you're right and it probably is a different question, but I was a little bit confused about what was being asked-- there isn't anything unusual about a master scrivener casting from a scroll. It's the scroll properties and creation method that differ for them, and the question title seemed ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, no material components are required.

During the creation of the scroll, the Master Scrivener feature says nothing about needing components to create the scroll. Thus, components are not required to create the scroll.

The rules for using scrolls clearly state that no components are required (unless stated otherwise). This is common, for example a Raise Dead scroll typically does not need the diamond that the Raise Dead spell normally requires. Thus, components are not needed during the casting of the spell.

I believe the game designers MEANT for this to be perk of the feature. I also believe (unlike some ... maybe?) that this is NOT over powered. This is a 10th level feature with a bunch of limitations. Only scrolls for 1st and 2nd level spells that have a casting time of one action can be created in this way. It can only be used by the creator and only once. Only one can be created a day. And, it expires after the creator takes a long rest.

I do not see a scenario where this could be "game breaking". It can't be used for Identify or Find Familiar as those have casting times that are not one action. I suppose you could whine about it and say "But, a Wizard could cast Continual Flame (without consuming a 50gp Ruby) once a day over an infinite number of days for a savings of an infinite amount." To which I respond with "So?"

Comment: Welcome to the site. This looks like a pretty good first answer. However, the idea is to have objective scientific style answers. Maybe you could remove some of the editorializing to make the answer more clear.

Answer (score -3):

**No - You will still have to pay for any expensive components,**

Under the idea of 5e being an [exception based ruleset](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/1056958922878111744), and "[there are no secret rules](https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/857269923134939136?lang=en)", unless it explicitly states you get a benefit, you do not get that benefit. Therefore, you have to pay them.

When and how they get used is probably a DM call, but it is probably best handled when the spell is transcribed.

I do not think this would be a good house rule either.  The expensive components are there for a reason, and doing away with that costs as well as the cost to scribe a spell might be a bridge too far.  IMO

Comment: I don't think this answer is wrong, but I think you should improve upon it to detail the negative impacts you anticipate occurring allowing a 10th level wizard to ignore the costly material components for a 1st or 2nd level spell once per day.